# How to change values in certain columns based on if the column names contain a string in another column in a dataframe for individual ids in R

Tags: r, for-loop, tidyr, data-cleaning, data-wrangling

Here is a dataset:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1, 2, 3),
                 substance = c("A,B", "B,C", "C,D"),
                 years_in_recovery.A = c(2, 4, 4),
                 years_in_recovery.B = c(5, 6, NA),
                 years_in_recovery.C = c(8, NA, 10),
                 years_in_recovery.D = c(11, 12, 13))
```

I want the code to go through each participant id (each row), look up if the name of the columns containing years_in_recovery contains the substances in the 'substance' column of that particular id (row). If it does, I want to keep the value, if it doesn't, I want to remove the value and replace it with NA. I want to do it for every row.

Edit: Just want to make sure that the column substance can contain multiple substances (e.g. A,B,C for every id)

I have been trying to look up everything, but couldn't find an answer, sorry beginner user in R.

Thank you for any help

I can't get anything to work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same approach as SamR's, slightly more compact:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df |>
  pivot_longer(
    !c(id, substance),
    names_to = c(".value", "medication"),
    names_pattern = "(.*)\\.(.*)"
  ) |> 
  mutate(across(
    years_in_recovery,
    \(x) if_else(str_detect(substance, medication), x, NA)
    ))
#> # A tibble: 12 × 4
#>       id substance medication years_in_recovery
#>    <dbl> <chr>     <chr>                  <dbl>
#>  1     1 A,B       A                          2
#>  2     1 A,B       B                          5
#>  3     1 A,B       C                         NA
#>  4     1 A,B       D                         NA
#>  5     2 B,C       A                         NA
#>  6     2 B,C       B                          6
#>  7     2 B,C       C                         NA
#>  8     2 B,C       D                         NA
#>  9     3 C,D       A                         NA
#> 10     3 C,D       B                         NA
#> 11     3 C,D       C                         10
#> 12     3 C,D       D                         13
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-15 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

This kind of data-wrangling operations is easily done using the `tidyverse`. In particular, we can use [`tidyr::pivot_longer()`](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/pivot_longer.html) to put the data in long form.

We can use base R [`strsplit()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/strsplit) to split your `substance` column from strings `"A, B"` to a list of vectors in the form `c("A", "B")`. Then in each row (using [`dplyr::rowwise()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/rowwise.html)), check whether `years_in_recovery` appears, and replace values with `NA` accordingly.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df_long <- df |>
    pivot_longer(
        -c(id, substance),
        names_to = "years_in_recovery",
        names_transform = \(x) gsub("years_in_recovery\\.", "", x)
    ) |>
    mutate(
        substance_split = strsplit(
            gsub("\\s+", "", substance), ","
        )
    ) |>
    rowwise() |>
    mutate(
        value = if_else(
            years_in_recovery %in% substance_split,
            value,
            NA
        )
    ) |>
    select(-substance_split)

df_long
#       id substance years_in_recovery value
#    <dbl> <chr>     <chr>             <dbl>
#  1     1 A, B      A                     2
#  2     1 A, B      B                     5
#  3     1 A, B      C                    NA
#  4     1 A, B      D                    NA
#  5     2 B, C      A                    NA
#  6     2 B, C      B                     6
#  7     2 B, C      C                    NA
#  8     2 B, C      D                    NA
#  9     3 C, D      A                    NA
# 10     3 C, D      B                    NA
# 11     3 C, D      C                    10
# 12     3 C, D      D                    13
```

If you want to put the data back in wide form that is straightforward:

```r
df_long |>
    pivot_wider(
        names_from = "years_in_recovery",
        names_prefix = "years_in_recovery."
    )
# A tibble: 3 × 6
#      id substance years_in_recovery.A years_in_recovery.B years_in_recovery.C years_in_recovery.D
#   <dbl> <chr>                   <dbl>               <dbl>               <dbl>               <dbl>
# 1     1 A, B                        2                   5                  NA                  NA
# 2     2 B, C                       NA                   6                  NA                  NA
# 3     3 C, D                       NA                  NA                  10                  13
```

Comment: Same approach, slightly more compact: 
`df |> pivot_longer(id, substance), names_to = c(".value", "medication"),  names_pattern = "(.*)\\.(.*)") |> mutate(across(years_in_recovery, \(x) if_else(str_detect(substance, medication), x, NA)))`

Comment: @dufei I think I see what you're getting at but something about that looks a bit wonky - your `names_to` argument is after the end of your `pivot_longer()`

Comment: Sorry, looks like it got jumbled up when I tried to remove some formatting. I posted it again as a separate answer with proper formatting!